# How can I make a function iterate over a multi-column list of positional arguments?

Tags: bash

I currently have a script that takes 3 positional arguments and performs a single operation using them.

I'd like to turn that into a script function that can be run for each 3-column space-separated line on an input file.

I'm at a bit of a loss for how to cleave off one line at a time and feed that line's 3 columns to the function as positional arguments.

If someone has a handy example of how this can be done in bash, that'd be swell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `read` command in a `while` loop:

```
while read -r arg1 arg2 arg3; do
    some_command "$arg1" "$arg2" "$arg3"
done < args.txt
```

Comment: Thanks much for this assistance!